# How to disable unicorn/prefer-module in typescript?

Tags: typescript, eslint

What is the proper way to disable `unicorn/prefer-module`?

I already tried this `/* eslint-disable unicorn/prefer-module */`

But I am getting `[eslint unicorn/prefer-module] [E] Definition for rule 'unicorn/prefer-module' was not found.`

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "argon2": "^0.28.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.6",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.12",
    "@types/express-mysql-session": "^2.1.2",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "@types/helmet": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^15.12.4",
    "eslint-plugin-unicorn": "^32.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.4",
    "xo": "^0.40.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "xo",
      "xo-typescript"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": "off",
      "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": "off"
    }
  },
  "xo": {
    "rules": {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-require-imports": 0,
      "@typescript-eslint/dot-notation": 0,
      "unicorn/prevent-abbreviations": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you installed the npm package? `eslint-plugin-unicorn`.
Would be helpful if you could also post your .eslintrc and package.json dependencies.

Comment: @hendrixchord I added the my package.json and my eslint is `eslintConfig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `unicorn` in eslintConfig section for `plugins`

```
"plugins": [
    "unicorn"
],
```

Reference: [Usage Documentation](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn#usage)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me. After playing around with the configuration, I found the following to work:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "xo": "^0.42.0"
  },
  "xo": {
    "rules": {
      "unicorn/prefer-module": 0
    }
  }
```

I'm using all the defaults - just not ready to change ALL my doe to modules just yet. Thought I'd share since it's a bit more concise.